# Two textviews overlayed over each other despite alignBottom

Tags: android, layout

Working on this app and laying out my data via `fragment_main.xml`.

I am currently trying to position my `display_pollen_type` right after `display_today_pollen` which is the percentage value you see. As you can tell, I have placed them in a cascading order, in this chronological display order `display_today_pollen`, `display_pollen_type`, and `display_today_date`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_today_pollen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="80sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_pollen_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/enter_area_code"
    android:layout_below="@+id/display_today_pollen"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_today_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/display_pollen_type"/>
```

I tried padding `display_pollen_type` with a `marginBottom`, but I believe it conflicts with `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`. Removing that did not solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align bottom just means the bottom of the two views will have the same y position.  If you want one to be to the left of the other, use layout_toLeftOf as well.  If you want one to be below the other, use layout_below instead of alignbottom.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that on my date display.